# How to successfully export a Magento 1.9 database ( MySQL 5.6) and Import it into MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, import, foreign-keys, export, magento-1.9

I have dumped a MySQL (5.6.40 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)) database (Magento 1.9) and try to import it into a MySQL (5.5.55-38.8-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 38.8, Revision 11f5bbd), during the importation, most of the scripts will execute fine, but some of them will fail like this:

```
10:48:04    
ALTER TABLE `affiliateplusprogram_category`   
ADD CONSTRAINT `affiliateplusprogram_category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`program_id`) REFERENCES `affiliateplusprogram` (`program_id`) ON DELETE 
CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,   ADD CONSTRAINT 
`affiliateplusprogram_category_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES 
`catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,   
ADD CONSTRAINT `affiliateplusprogram_category_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) 
REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
>      fails (`dailynuc_dailynu`.`#sql-1466_121c50b`, CONSTRAINT 
>      `affiliateplusprogram_category_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES 
>      `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UP) 
>      0.015 sec

Please guide me how to do this correctly, very appreciate for any kind help!

Answer (score 0):

just disable key checks with

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

at the top of sql dump.

also turn them back on when migration is finished

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```